# How to authenticate users using Azure AD in a Vue.js front-end and .Net 5 back-end

Tags: vue.js, asp.net-core, azure-active-directory

We are currently in the process of moving from .Net MVC to a Vue.js front-end. In our MVC version, we have a custom Attribute that uses Azure AD to authenticate users at certain pages. The attribute would just check if they were already logged into Microsoft and if not, redirect them to our organization's login. Since making the move to Vue.js, we get a **Cross-Origin Request Blocked** error when attempting the redirect. Looking online, it seemed like we needed to move to the Non-API solution Microsoft offers with OpenId. We are still having the same **Cross-Origin Request Blocked** issue with that solution as well. I am not sure where to go from here. Below is how our Startup.cs is setup and the controller I am testing with.

Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddHttpClient();
            services.AddMemoryCache();

            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(_configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("AuthorizeAccess",
                    policy => policy.Requirements.Add(new Helpside.Domain.Attributes.AuthorizeAccessAttribute()));
            });
         }
```

Controller

```
        [Authorize]
        [HttpGet("Test")]
        public JsonResult Test()
        {
            var response = "Test";

            return Json(response);
        }
```

Comment: Can you share the detailed Cross-Origin Request Blocked error message? In Asp.net core, to enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS), you need to use the UseCors() middleare enables the CORS middleware and use the AddCors method call adds CORS services to the app's service container, then set the allowed Origins, more detail information, see [Enable Cross-Origin Requests (CORS) in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/cors?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

> You are getting a Cross-Origin Request Blocked error when attempting the redirect.

Thanks @ `Zhi Lv` for the comments.

You need to Install-Package

[image]

`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Cors`

To fix this issue, you need to add the below code to your `Startup.cs` file.

```cs
builder.Services.AddCors(options => 
{ 
    options.AddPolicy(name:MyAllowSpecificOrigins, policy => 
    {            policy.WithOrigins("http://example.com", "http://www.contoso.com"); 
    });
});
```

Default Policy in `ConfigureServices` Method

```
public  void  ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)  {  
services.AddCors(options =>  
{ 
options.AddDefaultPolicy( builder =>  { builder.WithOrigins("[https://localhost:47531](https://localhost:47531/)",  "[http://localhost:4430](http://localhost:4430/)")  .AllowAnyHeader()  
.AllowAnyMethod(); 
}); });  
  }
```

In the `controller level` you need to add the attribute to allow all origins.

```
[EnableCors("AllowAllOrigins")]
```

The Vue app needs to handle the authentication with MSAL.js or ADAL.js.  And it has to acquire access tokens to your back-end API using the OAuth implicit flow.

For further information refer to the SO [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58446243/with-a-stack-like-vue-js-and-net-core-web-api-where-do-i-implement-auth-azur)